# Web3js event listen / subscribe to transactions to or from a wallet address

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js, binance-smart-chain

So I am connecting to Binance Smart Chain RPC websocket from Moralis.io. And trying to listen to wallet amount changes of a certain wallet address.

What I want to do is, I want to trigger a event whenever there is a transfer from or to this wallet address. I understand how to do it with BEP20 tokens but I require a solution to monitor the wallet address for BNB transfers.

The code that I put together:

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('URI'))

let options = {
address: '0xe....'
}

const subscribe = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', options, (err, res) => {})

subscribe.on('data', (txLog) => console.log(txLog))
```

This doesn't work when I send a certain amount of BNB to this account.

I went through the documentation of web3js but couldn't figure out.

I found a longer way around for this problem where someone suggests to listen to all pending transactions and try to get the transaction data of each of these transactions and evaluate if any of these are from or to the wallet address. But I think it is an extremely ineffective and inefficient way to do it as it requires someone to run their own node to do it in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 3):

> *listen to all pending transactions and try to get the transaction data of each of these transactions*

I agree that this is an ineffective way. But with the current state of the [JSON-RPC API](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API), it's still the most effective way available. Apart from using a 3rd party service that does all this work in the background and provides the data over their custom API.

*Note: The link goes to Ethereum documentation, but Binance Smart Chain [implements](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html#json-rpc-methods) the same JSON-RPC API.*

There's simply no method to subscribe to or poll incoming native transactions to a specified address.

And since web3, ethers.js, and many other libraries are wrappers of this API, they can only support methods that the API supports.

Comment: Want to know what are possible ways to identify native transactions to a wallet, say without WebSocket based Provider types.

Comment: @RudraPratapSinha With HTTP provider, you can poll new blocks and loop through transactions in each new block, looking for a transactions `to` the specified address. Polling means constantly asking for updates. So your code might query the block **each second for the latest block number**, and when it increases, it queries the node again to get transactions for this block.

Answer (score 0):

Moralis has Streams feature which allows to listen to transfer events of ERC20, native tokens and NFTs on BSC/ETH chains https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api/evm/how-to-listen-to-all-erc20-contract-transfers-over-certain-amount-sent-by-specific-address

Also, it's possible to self-host a blockchain crawler which will search for transactions from/to a given address, [here is a project which does that](https://github.com/ahmadbrainworks/fiddi)

Also Alchemy has similar feature, but they don't support BSC